# Sublime Text Won't Open Remote Via Caja (nautilus)

Tags: nautilus, ssh, mate, sublime-text

On my home machine (Ubuntu Mate 15.04) I use  and Sublime Text (3) to edit remote files on my server via the sftp connection created in Caja (Nautilus).

I'm traveling and on the laptop, it has the same setup (Ubuntu Mate, Sublime Text 3), but it won't open the files from Caja. No error is displayed.

Pluma (gedit) opens and saves the files without issue.

I'm far from home and can't see my notes or configuration... I did try installing sshfs, but it didn't help.

I posted on the Ubuntu Mate forum but haven't had any responses... Anyone have any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it..

This installs gvfs, then adds your user to the group..

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-fuse
sudo usermod -a -G fuse me
```

Where "me" is your user.

I can't accept my solution because I don't have the rep.. lol